# Updating user pool schema is not allowed from cloudformation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to make phone_number mutable through cloudformation templete, but getting below error

"Updating user pool schema is not allowed from cloudformation. Use the AddCustomAttributes API or the AWS Cognito Console to update user pool schema."

Below is my schema snippet:-

```
      {
        "Name": "phone_number",
        "AttributeDataType": "String",
        "Mutable": true,
        "Required": true
      },
```

Not sure why cloudformation is not able to update the UserPoolId.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add additional attributes to Cognito user pool once it has been created neither using CloudFormation, nor using the CLI or AWS console. You can only add custom attributes to an existing user pool.